# URL ReWrite with un-named parameter

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I would like this URL

http://alpha.Mysite.io/Car/Details/{4f2a95ed-3582-4486-8ef6-8a8e6731161f}

to redirect to

http://alpha.Mysite.io/Car/index.htm?Action=Details&guid={4f2a95ed-3582-4486-8ef6-8a8e6731161f}

The GUID parameter ({4f2a95ed-3582-4486-8ef6-8a8e6731161f}) is differenet each time so needs to be passed to the redirected URL.

I have the basic redirect working using a ReWriteMap,   however as soon as I add the nameless GUID paramter I get a 404 instead

Here's my section from webconfig

```
<rewrite>       
    <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite rule1 for carAPI">
            <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{carAPI:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="carAPI">
                <add key="/car/details/" value="/car/index.asp?Action=Details" />
            </rewriteMap>
        </rewriteMaps>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you do not need rewrite map. You can achieve everything with single rule:

```
<rule name="Rewrite rule1 for carAPI" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^Car/Details/([0-9A-Fa-f]{8}[-][0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-][0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-][0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-][0-9A-Fa-f]{12})" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/Car/index.htm?Action=Details&amp;guid={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

This rule will match urls like `Car/Details/{any valid .net guid}` and rewrite them into `Car/index.htm?Action=Details&guid={guid}`

Comment: I haven't forgotten this one,   tried your code as is and it didn't work,  but I'm sure it's me!

Comment: Can you try to change `Rewrite` with `Redirect` and confirm that it's reidrecting correctly. If not, can you please provide your url